# Netbeans, unicode identifier with c++/11 CLang breaks code assistance?

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, unicode, clang

[image]

Even if I disable Code Assistance, `à` is still highlighted in red. 
Is there a way to make Netbeans works with Unicode identifiers?

- OS Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
- Compiler is set to CLang.
- In Project.Properties.General: Under sources, Encoding is UTF-8.
- This simple project compile/run without errors.

Comment: Don't write non-portable code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Annex E explicitly allows this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Where exactly did you spot non-portable code?

Comment: @IInspectable & _@Baum_ OK, but it's ugly at least :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I don't like that either. If someone would use your username (w/o the space ofc) as a function name in his library, I could hardly use it because I can't type those characters.

Comment: @Maxime I can't really answer this question as I don't know Netbeans, but generally speaking: Unicode identifiers are a relatively new and *extremely* rarely used C++ feature, I would expect all kinds of tools to break when using it.

Comment: "Allowed in the standard" != "Portable". In particular, GCC doesn't handle extended identifiers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for your answer, it helps to understands why this feature could not work with actual tools. I'm asking Netbeans now, maybe I'll know more.